# Does Buxus grow berries or flowers in the winter?

Tags: shrubs, evergreens, foliage

Does all species of Buxus grow berries or flowers in the winter?

Comment: Your plant (in the other question) is not a Buxus: Buxus has opposite leaves, your plant has alternate leaves. The leave forms are similar to normal Buxus, but many Ilex (not the wild European one) have similar leaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buxus flowers are rather insignificant; their seeds are in an not-very-noticeable fruit that quickly dries to a capsule. Here's an [example](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1008/4432/products/Littleleaf_Boxwood_3.jpg?v=1543343207). Note that this is a close-up of the flowers. If you're looking for a broadleaf evergreen with showy fruits, then you'd be better off with an Ilex.